# How to open aspx page in internet explorer

Tags: asp.net

Im using devexpress reportviever and report toolbar.Find button cant work across browser because it used activex so only it can work internet explorer.My questons is how to aspx page open internet explorer?For example after redirection page open in internet explorer.
Thank you all of members

Comment: Are you asking how to force somebody to open Internet Explorer from the non-IE browser they're currently using?  If so, then I don't believe it's possible (thankfully!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can't switch browsers between page navigation you have no control over that. The server just serves up content, the browsing is client side and usually limited to the same browser.

If you have to use Internet Explorer then you will have to warn your users when they land in your website/page.

Comment: I need only a page open in internet explorer.I found a code and write page load.   ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe","http://localhost:51911/WebForm1.aspx");
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            Process proc = Process.Start(psi);
            proc.CloseMainWindow();                                      It work but it cant stop.Numerous explorer open.Do you know about it?

Answer (score 0):

Default browser for all aspx page :

```
If you right click on any page other than default.aspx you will not get the "browse with" option.
```

You need to set Internet explorer in default browser .If you open new window then they automatically open your page in new IE browser window

Use the below the javascript method to open window

```
function openWindow(url)
    {
        window.open(url, 'windowname', 'scrollbars=0,resizable=0,status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0');
        return false;
    }
```

Put a link button on your page

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkOpenWindow" Text="Attach" runat="server" OnClientClick="openWindow('X01.aspx?ID=5')"></asp:LinkButton>
```